# Truth-Functional Logic - At most one of 2

Tags: logic

Exactly as the title says - the question is, "At most one of A or B."

The only symbols we've learned so far are negation (not), conjunction (and), disjunction (inclusive or), material conditional (if x then y), and material biconditional (if and only if).

The only way that I can think to write it is as follows (I'm sorry, I can't figure out how to get the symbols):

(A  if not C) or (C if not A)

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lnot(A\land B)$.

($\lnot$ stands for negation, $\land$ stands for conjuction)

Comment: Ohh that makes sense. How would you say at most one of 3 (1 of A or B or C)

Comment: @Josh $\lnot(A\land B)\land\lnot(A\land C)\land\lnot(B\land C)$.

Comment: Sorry just one last question - how would you write 'exactly 1 of 2'?

Comment: @Josh $(A\lor B)\land\lnot(A\land B)$.

Comment: @Josh Also, $\lnot A\leftrightarrow B$ is possible. (In classical logic) But remember, $\rightarrow$ and $\leftrightarrow$ can be constructed from $\land$, $\lor$ and $\lnot$. ($A\rightarrow B:= \lnot A\land B, A\leftrightarrow B:= (A\rightarrow B)\land(B\rightarrow A)$)